# how to set different authentication in firebase for web and android

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am creating an app which has sign in/sign up option and the authentication will come from firebase. I also crate a web page which work as admin panel and its also get the authentication from firebase.So how could I separate this authentication for sign in that if anyone sign up from app they can not sign in to the web with their account? How could I just set private account which can only access the web page account?

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do this but you can simply create a different Firebase project for each (web and android app). This would prevent the same user from having access to both.

Comment: But I have to do it in same project, as I have to pass same value from web to android. Just Authentication should be different.